Sonner toast is not rendering toast on component mount
I want to show a toast when my client side component mounts.
I'm using sonner library to show toast, it's working fine when we use button to show toast.
I make an example app to show the problem. Here is the github link https://github.com/saifion33/Nextjs-toast-problem
I'm trying to trigger a toast when component mount on client side.
app/layout.tsx
<html lang="en">
  <body className={`${geistSans.variable} ${geistMono.variable} antialiased`}>
    {children}
    <ToasterComp />
  </body>
</html>

ToasterComp
"use client"

import { Toaster } from "sonner"

const ToasterComp = () => {
  return (
    <Toaster closeButton richColors duration={3000} />
  )
}

export default ToasterComp

app/page.tsx
import MyComponent from "@/components/MyComponent";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="text-center">
      <h1 className=" my-10 text-blue-500 text-3xl">Sonner render problem example app</h1>
      <p className="text-slate-800">
        Reload this page, if you don&apos;t see a toast then this is not working. if you click the button you will see a toast.
      </p>
      <MyComponent />
    </div>
  );
}

MyComponent
"use client"

import { useEffect } from "react"
import { toast } from "sonner"

const MyComponent = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    toast.success("This is the toast that will be shown.")
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        className="bg-blue-500 text-stone-50 border-2 border-slate-900 py-2 px-4 rounded-lg mt-4"
        onClick={() => toast.info('You clicked the button.')}
      >
        Show toast
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default MyComponent


I am not sure it would but, maybe try putting Toast component above children
<html lang="en">
  <body className={`${geistSans.variable} ${geistMono.variable} antialiased`}>
    <ToasterComp />
    {children}
  </body>
</html>

Or try lazy loading the component with ssr:false, in which you have to show toast on component mount.
const MyComponent = dynamic(()=>import("@/components/MyComponent"),{ssr:false})

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="text-center">
      <h1 className=" my-10 text-blue-500 text-3xl">Sonner render problem example app</h1>
      <p className="text-slate-800">
        Reload this page, if you don&apos;t see a toast then this is not working. if you click the button you will see a toast.
      </p>
      <MyComponent />
    </div>
  );
}


According to documentation:

To render a toast on initial page load it is required that the
function toast() is called inside of a setTimeout or
requestAnimationFrame.

Update to dispatch the toast in a timeout:
useEffect(() => {
  const timerId = setTimeout(() => {
    toast.success("This is the toast that will be shown.");
  });

  return () => {
    clearTimeout(timerId);
  };
}, []);

In the case that you render your React application into a React.StrictMode component that will double-mount the components and run certain lifecycle methods and hook callbacks twice and dispatch two toasts (!!), you can use a React Ref to track that you've already dispatched the mounting toast.
Example:
const mountedRef = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
  let timerId;

  if (!mountedRef.current) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      toast.success("This is the toast that will be shown.");
    });
  }

  mountedRef.current = true;

  return () => {
    clearTimeout(timerId);
  };
}, []);

Note that it is currently generally considered a React anti-pattern to use React refs to "track" when a component mounts to conditionally apply logic, a useEffect hook cleanup function should be returned to unsubscribe/cancel/cleanup up any pending/asynchronous logic. I believe this is a valid edge case since this sonner library doesn't export/include any way to cancel the dispatched toast from the first "initial render", so you'll need to not dispatch the toast on the second "initial render".
